# Is there some significance to the number 8848?

Tags: assassins-creed-3-liberation

One of the trophies for *Assassin's Creed: Liberation* reads as follows:

> **Climber**
>   Climb 8848 meters

Considering that I completed the entire game only climbing about 2,500 meters (according to my stats), I was wondering where they came up with this weird number of theirs. Going from a math perspective, I tried seeing if 8848 converted into something sane...

**8848 meters is...**

- 5.49789 miles
- 9676.29 yards
- 29028.9 feet
- 8.848 kilometers

Nothing really stands out there...

So, does the number **8848** have some sort of significance that I've missed somewhere, or is it just a random number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

8,848 meters is the height of [Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest), so likely this achievement is related to climbing the same distance as that historically and geographically significant peak.